# increase ohloh rank

Tags: git, github

how can I commit into ohloh?
can I add my projects from github to my ohloh account?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.ohloh.net/p/new allows you to register your project.

Comment: yes, tnx. I found that i should create a repository in sites like github, then submit my project in ohloh.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your project to ohloh easy as use ;)

https://www.ohloh.net/p/new